# Prove that the sequence is a Martingale.

Tags: random-variables, martingales

Consider an urn that initially contains b black balls and w white balls. At every iteration, we draw a
random ball is chosen and the chosen ball is replaced by c > 1 balls of the same color. Let $X_i$ denote
the fraction of black balls after i-th draw. Prove that $X_0$, $X_1$, . . . is a martingale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=c-1$. Let $k=b+w$ be the initial number of balls.
Then $X_{n}(k+dn)$ is the number of black balls at the $n$-th step. 
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{n+1}\mid X_{n}\right] & =X_{n}\frac{X_{n}\left(k+dn\right)+d}{k+d\left(n+1\right)}+\left(1-X_{n}\right)\frac{X_{n}\left(k+dn\right)}{k+d\left(n+1\right)}\\
 & =X_{n}\left[\frac{X_{n}\left(k+dn\right)}{k+d\left(n+1\right)}+\frac{d}{k+d\left(n+1\right)}\right]+\left(1-X_{n}\right)\frac{X_{n}\left(k+dn\right)}{k+d\left(n+1\right)}\\
 & =X_{n}\left[\frac{d}{k+d\left(n+1\right)}+\frac{\left(k+dn\right)}{k+d\left(n+1\right)}\right]\\
 & =X_{n}.
\end{align*}

Comment: A little doubt, I thought we have to prove that E[$X_{n+1}$|$X_n$,$X_{n-1}$,...,$X_1$] = $X_n$, Why haven't you considered the previous $X_i$'s? Am I missing something? I asked cause we have been taught that way.

Comment: In our case, $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid X_n, X_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0] = \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid X_n]$ since you don't get any additional information from knowing the previous states. In particular, this is a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help